# How to HttpPost from a Wcf service to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, http

First of all make be declare that I am a newbie.

Now, I have a website that sends a string to a method in **Wcf Service A** which should POST it to another **wcf service B**

I am able to send the string from web Application to Service A but I cant seem to HttpPost it to B. Can you please throw some light?

**WEB APP:**

```
SpendWcfRef.SPEND WcfSpend = new SpendWcfRef.SPEND(); 
        string str=WcfSpend.TestPost("abc"); //this is service A
```

**Service A**

```
 [OperationContract]
    string TestPost(string test);



public string TestPost(string test)
    {

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:58486/CIBIL_WCF/Service.svc/TestInsert?testobj="+test+"");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();//The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
        string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return "Yeey".ToString();
    }
```

**Service B**

```
      [OperationContract]
        string TestInsert(string testObj);

 public string TestInsert(string testobj)
    {

        return testobj.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add ServiceB as a Service Reference in your ServiceA project ? That way, instead of using the HttpWebRequest, you get a proxy object that you can use to call ServiceB

Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

Comment: Assume that I have to send data through HTTP Post. There is no other option.

Comment: In that case you need to form the proper SOAP request and do a POST. A  WCF Service needed not have a REST endpoint by default. So a simple HTTP GET request on it will not work. You also need to consider other stuff like security while sending the request. A simple way to figure out what SOAP structure to follow is to take a network trace from an existing working client(like SOAPUI) and try to replicate it.